# What is the correct way to do REST urls?

Tags: api, url, rest

```
domain.com/blog/How-To-Code/3 (page 3)
domain.com/user/alicejohnson/comments
```

OR

```
domain.com/How-To-Code/3
domain.com/alicejohnson/comments
```

Facebook and Quora does it the 2nd way: http://www.quora.com/Swimming/Can-one-swim-from-New-Zealand-to-Australia  They eliminate the noun and go straight to the object.

Stackoverflow does it the first way: [What is the correct way to do REST urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971662/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-rest-urls)

Which should I do?

Most importantly, **how does this affect SEO**?

Also, if I do the 2nd version, how do I go about writing the "router" for that?

Comment: Any URL that communicates the parameters is "the right way".  REST does not imply any particular way of forming the URL.

Comment: Note that this question can be linked with http://stackoverflow.com/q/14971662/581994 -- It's an arbitrary "naming" scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps think of 'blog' and 'user' above as namespaces.  If there are multiple uses for How-To-Code you might have to put something behind it.

Some people tend to be pedantic about "proper REST" but I try to avoid this.  I would design your URL schemes so it fits your needs, works well with tools and allows you to simply paste URLs into a browser to test your code.